# Load Excel file into database as varbinary using python

Tags: python, sql, varbinary

I have `Output1.xlsx` and `Output2.xml` placed at location - `C:\Desktop\SampleTestFiles`

How do I write python code to load them into database table - `[TEST].[dbo].[tables]` as `varbinary` datatype such that each row in files table indicate single file?

Apparently, I have used `SQL bulk import` but this doesn't seems to work if my server is placed at remote location and files are placed at local directory.

```
Query = '''
        DECLARE @Document AS VARBINARY(MAX);
        SELECT @Document = CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FROM OPENROWSET( BULK '%s', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Doc;
        INSERT INTO[TEST].[dbo].[Files]([file],[file_name])
        select @Document, ?                 
        '''%Excelfilepath
values = (file_name)
connsql = self.sql_connection()
connsql.cursor().execute(Query, values)
connsql.cursor().commit()
connsql.close()
```

Comment: can you share me what is the value that contains  Excelfilepath  ?

Comment: Excelfilepath ='C:\Desktop\SampleTestFiles\Output1.xlsx'

Comment: yes , the problem is that your are trying bulk from your local and another server...but I think there is not option using BULK for this example....can be another option?...or is necessary to use this way ?

Comment: Other option also works. My goal is just to populate file in varbinary format into files table.